# Use of the word "provenance"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can the word *provenance* be used in reference to a person, or should it only be used for objects?

For example, would it be improper to ask someone for their provenance?

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/provenance), and [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/provenance), for instance, only mention it being used for 'things' / 'objects'.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary definitions usually restrict the association of 'provenance' to [inanimate] **things**:

> **provenance** [noun]: the place of origin or earliest known history of something.
>
> - *an orange rug of Iranian provenance*
>
> the beginning of something's existence; something's origin.
>
> - *they try to understand the whole universe, its provenance and fate*" a record of ownership of a work of art or an antique, used as a
>   guide to authenticity or quality.
> - *the manuscript has a distinguished provenance*

[[Oxford Languages, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=provenance+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=provenance+meaning&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqDwgAEEUYOxiDARixAxiABDIPCAAQRRg7GIMBGLEDGIAEMgYIARBFGEAyBwgCEAAYgAQyBwgDEAAYgAQyBwgEEAAYgAQyBwgFEAAYgAQyBwgGEAAYgAQyBwgHEAAYgATSAQk3NzY5ajFqMTWoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

> **provenance** [variable noun] [plural where appropriate, provenances] [formal]
>
> The provenance of something is the place that it comes from or that it
> originally came from.
>
> - Kato was fully aware of the provenance of these treasures. [+ of]
> - He had no idea of its provenance.

[[Collins; adjusted slightly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/provenance)]

> **provenance**: ... 2: the history of ownership of a valued object or work of art or literature

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provenance)]

However, it is not unusual to speak of a valued animal's provenance:

> - *Tracking and recording a horse's provenance makes these ... could be an offence not to have registered your horse's provenance with an
>   approved* ...

[[Australian Parliament House](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22horse%27s+provenance%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=%22horse%27s+provenance%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQoxMDYzM2owajE1qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

And Merriam-Webster (op cit) licenses the broadening to cover associations, committees etc:

> - *Self- serving bureaucracies are seeking to silence those who would*
>   *question their provenance and purpose.* [Caitlin Huston, The Hollywood
>   Reporter, 21 Sep. 2023]

But applying the term to individual persons could be quirky, tongue-in-cheek – or rarefied – and could even be seen as insulting. Google 2-grams for 'his provenance' and 'her provenance' show that these are very much less commonly used than 'its provenance':

[image]

So *asking a **stranger** for their provenance* is not recommended.